# Why is explicit call to operator<< ambiguous?

Tags: c++, iostream

Here is the simple code :

```
int main()
{
    int x=0;
    std::cout<<x; 
    operator<<(std::cout,x); //ambiguous

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the `operator<<(std::cout,x)` call ambiguous but not `std::cout<<x;`? Thanks

Comment: Depending on your compiler, it may actually say which functions it considers in the overload resolution. You might check that to understand why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that for outputting integers, [`operator<<` is an `std::ostream` *member* function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).

So to explicitly call the operator function you should do e.g.

```
std::cout.operator<<(x);
```

The [stand-alone `operator<<` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) is for characters and strings.